# Power Shell script keep on missing after extraction of Zip folder using Python script

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, windows-10, zip

I am writing a python script to download zip file from URL and extract it then running power shell scripts to install the service.

Things work well with downloading zip and extraction, but when i am trying to run power shell script I am getting file not found error. suddenly the script is missing.

When I try to copy it from another folder its not showing up and it also missing from the source folder also.

Please help me to understand this problem

```
def make_zip(name):
    cur_dir = os.getcwd()
    with zipfile.ZipFile(name, "w") as z:
        return True

def download(name):
    url = "https://XXXXX/downloads/XXX-7.8.0-windows-x86_64.zip"
    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    handle = open(name, "wb")
    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=512):
        if chunk:
            handle.write(chunk)
    handle.close()
    
def extract(name):
    cur_dir = os.getcwd()
    with zipfile.ZipFile(name, 'r') as z:
        z.extractall(cur_dir)

def install(service):
    service = "test.ps1"
    command_options = ["PowerShell.exe", "-ExecutionPolicy", "UnRestricted", "-File", service]
    process_result = subprocess.run(command_options, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, 
    universal_newlines = True)  # CALL PROCESS

    print(process_result.returncode)  # PRINT RETURN CODE OF PROCESS  0 = SUCCESS, NON-ZERO = FAIL
    print(process_result.stdout)      # PRINT STANDARD OUTPUT FROM POWERSHELL
    print(process_result.stderr)      # PRINT STANDARD ERROR FROM POWERSHELL ( IF ANY OTHERWISE ITS 
    NULL|NONE )
    if process_result.returncode == 0:  # COMPARING RESULT
        Message = "Success !"
    else:
        Message = "Error Occurred !"


makezip('example')   #creates example.zip file
download('example')  #downloads the url file into example zip
extract('example')   #extracts the zip
install('example')   #to install the service
```

Comment: Code in your post omits the call to `install()`, please update it

Comment: the install function is returning file not found exception, because after extraction the zip file and power shell script are missing, I have no idea why this is happening is it problem with python script or an internal error.